# Calculating t and epsilon for a computationally indistinguishable pseudo random generator

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I have a PRG $G : \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{2n}$.

How would you go about calculating the optimal size of $n$ given that you have

$$\epsilon = \cfrac{1}{2^{80}}$$

and, $t = 2$ years for a PRG that is (t,$\epsilon$) pseudorandom i.e

$$| Pr[D(r) = 1] -  Pr[D(G(s)) = 1]| ≤ \operatorname{\epsilon}(n).$$

I know that I should take into account how many computations a computer can execute per second, but I'm unclear as to how exactly I end up finding $n$.

Comment: pick one of $2^{60},2^{70},2^{80},2^{90}$, this is really depend on the capability of your advarsery.

Comment: Excuse me, but how does the 2 years fit in..?